# Is it possible to write a MATLAB script that can give command line input to a function?

Tags: matlab, testing, input

I am writing MATLAB code that will fit together with other MATLAB functions that I cannot modify. Some of these existing functions take input from the command line. Is there a way I can write a test script in MATLAB that can call these functions, and then provide the input as the user would?
ie. if I have a function:

```
function y = f(x)
z = input('Enter number: ');
y = x + z;
end
```

Is there a way to have a script call f and provide z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are looking for a non elegant solution.**

**If you are looking for a potentially dangerous solution.**

Then you might try this: write a function named "input" as follows:

```
function a=input(str)
% THIS IS THE DUMMY VERSION OF THE
% MATLAB BUILT-IN FUNCTION "input"
global dummy_input

disp('WARNING!!!')
disp('MATLAB "input" built-in function overridded')

disp(['Setting dummy_inpt'])
a=dummy_input;
end
```

Declare a `global` variable either in the script you use to test the function and in your "dummy" `input` function.

Assign the desired value to the `global variable` as follows:

```
global dummy_input

x=3;

dummy_input=123;

y=my_func(x)

dummy_input=42.13;

y=my_func(x)
```

If `my_func` is the function you post in the question, you will obtain:

```
WARNING!!!
MATLAB "input" built-in function overridded
Setting dummy_inpt

y =

   126

WARNING!!!
MATLAB "input" built-in function overridded
Setting dummy_inpt

y =

   45.1300
```

I've added the printing of the warnings in the "dummy" input function yust as a remainder ...

You do not need to modify the function you want to test, when it will call `input` to get a number from the user, it will call your "dummy" input.

**Version 2 of the "dummy" input function**

This version of the "dummy" input function allows autonatically handling multiple request of input values.

It requires the user knows in advance how many times the "original" `input` function is called.

No additional `global counter` is required.

It is sufficient the change the definition of the `global parameter` in the script, declaring it as an array containing the set of input the user want to assign:

```
global input_list
input_list=[27    30     5    31    21]
```

In the "dummy" `input` function, the first element of the array is assigned to the output variable, then the it is deleted:

```
a=input_list(1);
input_list(1)=[];
```

the code of the updated version of the function is the following:

```
function a=input(str)
% THIS IS THE DUMMY VERSION OF THE
% MATLAB BUILT-IN FUNCTION "input"
global input_list

disp('WARNING!!!')
disp('MATLAB "input" built-in function overridded')

disp(' ')
disp(' ')
disp(' ')
if(isempty(input_list))
   error('Error in DUMMY input: no more input data')
else
   disp(['Setting dummy_input ' num2str(input_list(1))])
   a=input_list(1);
   disp(' ')
   disp(' ')
   disp(' ')

   input_list(1)=[];
end

end
```

An `error` is generated in case the input array becomes `empty` (by deleting its element at each call) before the end of the script.

I've also added some calls to `disp` to make more "clear" the output on the Command Window.

Also the "dummy" `input` function print a message on the Command Window telling which input values has been assigned.

**Make sure to remove your dummy "input" function at the end**

Hope this helps.

Comment: And is there a slicker way of generalizing it so that it works when f has multiple prompts, besides maintaining a global counter as well?

Comment: I've added an updated version of the `dummy input` function at the end of my previous answer. If I correctly understood your request, it handles multiple assignement of input values without needing to add an additional `global` varaible (a counter)`.

Comment: Great. I ended up using cell arrays because I needed mixed kinds of input. Same solution with some curly brackets.