# Answer input() automatically

Tags: matlab, undocumented-behavior

Here's a potentially out-of-the box question: I would like to automatically 'answer' an `input()` command in Matlab. How could this be achieved?

Background: There's a static piece of code I need to work with, but would like to automate.

```
function test()
  nested_func();
    %nested function calls input
    function nested_func()
        name=input('Please tell us your name: ','s');
    end
end
```

I tried Java robots to enter things into console, however this should only run when the input function is in effect and therefore also pauses all commands, so nothing else can be entered:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
rob=Robot;
disp('Henry'); %types 'Henry' as 'fake input'
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); %presses enter key
```

**EDIT:** adapted example to include nested function calling `input()` as example for GUI calling it

Comment: Have you tried piping your answer to matlab in the terminal? I mean something like: `echo "somename" | matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('path/to/your/script.m'); exit;"`

Comment: good idea, unfortunately in my specifc case Matlab will only ask after a dialog interaction, so I guess that's hardly possible

Comment: I've answered to a similar question in the past, [perhaps it could help you too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30789679/4806927)

Comment: @il_raffa interesting. Defining input temporarily might be the perfect solution, I'll try

Comment: @il_raffa this does not work in my case because input is used within a function (even GUI), so if input in the 'base' workspace is set to some value, this is ineffective for the scope of the function

Comment: At present I do not have access to MatLab therefore I can not make any test, but you can try adapting that approach by befining the "dummy" input function within the GUI end pass the input using the function "guidata" instead of definig them as global variables.

Comment: Also, please, post the relevant part of the GUI code, it will help understanding your problem.

Comment: @il_raffa adapted example

Comment: You could follow the suggested approach, but defining a function `input` as an M-file in a directory at the beginning of your MATLAB path.